# Facebook share ignores meta tags

Tags: php, facebook, web-crawler, meta

I would like to customize Facebook links shared manually to Facebook, that is, one pastes a link to a Facebook post and then the Facebook crawler gathers data.

Test case: [qooh.me/ajpika](http://qooh.me/ajpika)

I have this code:

```
<?php
if (fRequest::get('action', null, false) == "index") {
?>
<meta property="og:title" content="Ask or tell me anything anonymously" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>">
<?php
}
```

which generates the following HTML at the test case:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Ask or tell me anything anonymously">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://qooh.me/ajpika">
```

so far, so good. However, the `meta` definitions I use are not handled by Facebook crawler in the way I would expect. This is how it is shown:

[image]

As you can see, the `title` is `Qoohme`, which is probably taken from here:

```
<title>Qoohme</title>
```

yet, I would like the `title` to be `"Ask or tell me anything anonymously"` as defined for `og:url`

Also, the URL shown is `QOOH.ME` instead of the expected `QOOH.ME/AJPIKA`

Why is my solution not meeting my expectation?

EDIT:

According to the comment of Fred -ii- I can confirm that one of the main issues was that Facebook crawler cached the page I have been testing at. By trying another page, the `title` was the expected "`Ask or tell me anything anonymously`". I have been testing at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) page, where I have cleared the cache of the page I have been testing at. However, the URL shown with gray text is still `QOOH.ME` and not the expected `QOOH.ME/AJPIKA`, but if I click on the post, it redirects to the expected page of qooh.me/ajpika.

Comment: the only thing I can think of is to try their developer debug URL and have it fetch it again. If that page was already fetched by Facebook, then it could be a cache issue. I'm not 100% sure about it, but you can try it.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I can confirm that the issue is related to caching. If I paste a URL which was not cached by Facebook crawler, then it shows the correct title of "Ask or tell me anything anonymously". However, the URL is still QOOH.ME instead of the expected URL of QOOH.ME/USERNAME.